# jQuery or JavaScript get element near other element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, position

How (using either jQuery, or JavaScript...)

```
<div style="background-color:red;height:10px;width:10px;float:left;"></div>
<div style="background-color:red;height:10px;width:10px;float:left;margin-left:25px;"></div>
<br>
<div style="background-color:red;height:10px;width:10px;margin-left:15px;" id="2">
```

Do I get what element is closest to `id=2`? I need this type of selector, and any help would be appreciated. :)

Note that I don't mind setting a `position:relative` or `absolute` and `left:(number)px` to these elements.

I need a code that would work in a dynamic environment; you know, when blocks keep getting created and keep scrolling forwards and changing left position. Could I use `.position()` perhaps? Somehow?

Thank you. :)

Comment: Closest, as in close to each other on the screen, or close in the DOM ?

Comment: no, i want close togethe ron the screeen, not the dom, thanks @adeneo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a fun thought experiment...

To solve this, you'd probably want to calculate the `offset` of each element, and compare those coordinates (`top` and `left`) to other elements.

Assuming you want to find the element closest to `compareEl`, and you have `compareElTop` and `compareElTop`, loop through all elements on screen (except `compareEl`), and do something like this:

```
var topDiff = Math.abs(compareElTop-elements[x].offset().top);
    leftDiff = Math.abs(compareElLeft-elements[x].offet.left);
```

Pair with the lowest `topDiff+leftDiff` is closest.

[Here is a nice jsFiddle for you to play around with! All kinds of awesome.](http://jsfiddle.net/julianlam/dQMXY/1/)

Comment: That... is... so... helpful. Thanks a heap.

Answer (score 1):

For example if you want to get DOM elements that is closest with #2:

```
    <span>before</span>
    <div style="background-color:red;height:10px;width:10px;margin-left:15px;" id="2">  </div>
    <span>after</span>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
    var prevIt = $('#2').prev();
    var nextIt = $('#2').next();
});
```

Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hicurin/Uysp6/2/)

Comment: no, i want close togethe ron the screeen, not the dom, thanks